# Changing the font size of document title

Tags: fontsize

A publication I am submitting to has the rather annoying requirement of needing the document title to be size 16pt (and the regular text size being 12pt, which I know how to do). I have absolutely no idea how to change the font size of the title (beyond adding `\Large`, `\LARGE` etc. but none of these correspond to 16pt).

How would I go about setting the font size of the title to a specific size?

Comment: You should mention the class you're using. You need to register also on this site in order to be able to comment and edit your question.

Comment: Do the publications' style guidelines also specify (a) the *distance* between two consecutive lines of text, for both the 12pt and 16pt font sizes, (b) whether the title should be set in **bold** or regular weight, and (c) the font that is to be used (e.g., Times Roman, Helvetica, etc.)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For small sections of text, write a command:

```
\newcommand*{\TitleFont}{%
      \usefont{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}%
      \fontsize{16}{20}%
      \selectfont}
```

which you can use as

```
\title{\TitleFont ....}
```